# Get base64 String from Image URI

Tags: java, android, base64

I have content:// URI of an image and I want to convert it to base64. I don't know how to do this.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==123 && resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedfile = data.getData(); //The uri with the location of the file
        if (selectedfile != null) {
            Log.e("image", selectedfile.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should tell which problems you encountered doing so.

Comment: show the code in which part you are facing the problem

Comment: I don't have code for this part because I don't know how to convert content URI to base64. I'm asking you for some kind of solution.

Comment: If you had obtained a file:// uri. Then whould you have known?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it by using 2 steps.

1- URI to Bitmap conversion:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==123 && resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedfile = data.getData(); //The uri with the location of the file
        if (selectedfile != null) {
           Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedfile);
        }
    }
}
```

2- Bitmap to Base64 String conversion:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
byte[] byteArray = outputStream.toByteArray();

String encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

As a result:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==123 && resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedfile = data.getData(); //The uri with the location of the file
        if (selectedfile != null) {
           Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedfile);

           ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
           bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
           byte[] byteArray = outputStream.toByteArray();

           //Use your Base64 String as you wish
           String encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
        }
    }
}
```